# Accept decimals numbers with comma and dot

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing a uwp app, where I have a textbox, which I want to accept only decimals, comma or dot (for example: 1.5 or 1.5 or 1.50 or 1.50)
With the value entered in this textbox, and after clicking a button in the app will do an operation:

```
double value= Convert.ToDouble(inputBox.Text);
```

InputBox is my textbox where the user enters the numbers.
If I enter for example 1,50 does not give error, and does the operation I want. If I enter 1.50 it gives this error, in this line of code I presented:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify separator(s) (`.` and `,`) *manually* and try parsing with both formats:

```
string source = "123,456"; // "123.456" (with dot) will be accepted as well
double result;

if (double.TryParse(source, 
                    NumberStyles.Number, //TODO: you may want to change style
                    new NumberFormatInfo() { 
                      NumberDecimalSeparator = ".", 
                      NumberGroupSeparator = "" }, 
                    out result) ||
    double.TryParse(source, 
                    NumberStyles.Number, //TODO: you may want to change style
                    new NumberFormatInfo() { 
                      NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", 
                      NumberGroupSeparator = "" }, 
                    out result)) 
{
    // result contains parsed source value
}
else 
{
    // source is not a valid double
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `||` instead of `&&` (between the 2 `tryParse`)?

Comment: @Gian Paolo: Thank you! it should have been `||` for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're the best! That's what I wanted, now this solves my problem. Thank you very much!